# Deadlock in book <The Go Programming Language>, how it would happen and why it happen?

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

There are several times in this book talk about `deadlock` regarding to incorrect usage of `goroutine` and `channel`, and I failed to grasp why the deadlock happen.

First thing I want to say is that, I know channel send&receive will block until there is items to be read or rooms to send items into, and maybe that's the deep reason of some `deadlock`. But please enlighten me with some explanation  according to the following excerpt from the book:

## Page 240

This code is to concurrently crawl urls, BFS style:

```golang
func main() {
    worklist := make(chan []string)

    // Start with the command-line arguments.
    go func() { worklist <- os.Args[1:] }()

    // Crawl the web concurrently.
    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    for list := range worklist {
        for _, link := range list {
            if !seen[link] {
                seen[link] = true
                go func(link string) {
                    worklist <- crawl(link)
                }(link)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

quoting book's second paragraph:

> ...the initial send of the command-line arguments to the worklist must run in its own goroutine to avoid deadlock, a stuck situation in which both the main goroutine and a crawler goroutine attempt to send to each other while neither is receiving...

suppose the initial send to `worklist` is not in its own goroutin, I imagine it works like this:

1. main goroutine send initial to `worklist`, block until received
2. the `for range` receive the initial item, so unblock the `worklist` channel
3. the crawler goroutine send its items into `worklist`, loop...

So to my understanding, it won't block and deadlock. Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**: @mkopriva helped me realized since step 1 is blocked, step 2,3 is unreachable. So I'm clear on this one.

## Page 243

This deadlock situation might be the same as in page 240:

```golang
func main() {
    worklist := make(chan []string) // list of URLs, may have duplicates
    unseenLinks := make(chan string) // de-duplicated URLs

    // Add command-lin arguments to worklist.
    go func() { worklist <- os.Args[1:] }()

    // Create 20 crawler goroutines to fetch each unseen link.
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        go func() {
            for link := range unseenLinks {
                foundLinks := crawl(link)
                go func() { worklist <- foundLinks }()
            }
        }()
    }

    // The main goroutine de-duplicates worklist items
    // and sends the unseen ones to the crawlers.
    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    for list := range worklist {
        for _, link := range list {
            if !seen[link] {
                seen[link] = true
                unseenLinks <- link
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I put omit `go` inside the `for-range` loop, how the deadlock happen?

Comment: *"I imagine it works like this: ...."* -- In your imagined execution model, if `1` blocks how do you get to `2`?

Comment: Right... I just realized this. My mind is blocked. Still working on the  second code snippet.

Comment: In case it's unclear, the second snippet would have the same problem if you'd remove the goroutine from the loop. The `for link := range unseenLinks` loop will not exit until something *closes* `unseenLinks`.

Comment: @mkopriva I see. Thank you! Can you write down an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first snippet, the initial channel send needs to be done in a goroutine because without a goroutine the statement would block indefinitely and the execution would never reach the loop that receives from that channel. i.e. To get from `1.` to `2.`, `1.` needs to be done in a goroutine. If `1.` blocks however, then `2.` is never reached.

Where the comments start is where the execution stops:

```golang
func main() {
    worklist := make(chan []string)

    worklist <- os.Args[1:]
// 
//     seen := make(map[string]bool)
//     for list := range worklist {
//         for _, link := range list {
//             if !seen[link] {
//                 seen[link] = true
//                 go func(link string) {
//                     worklist <- crawl(link)
//                 }(link)
//             }
//         }
//     }
// }
```

---

In the second snippet you have a `for-range` loop over a channel, such a loop will NOT exit until the ranged-over channel is closed. That means that, while the body of such a loop may continue to get executed, the code after the loop-with-unclosed-channel will never be reached.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

> 4. For channels, the iteration values produced are the successive values sent on the channel **until the channel is [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close)**. If the channel
>    is nil, the range expression blocks forever.

Where the comments start is where the execution stops:

```golang
func main() {
    worklist := make(chan []string)
    unseenLinks := make(chan string)

    go func() { worklist <- os.Args[1:] }()

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        for link := range unseenLinks {
//            foundLinks := crawl(link)
//            go func() { worklist <- foundLinks }()
//        }
//     }
// 
//     seen := make(map[string]bool)
//     for list := range worklist {
//         for _, link := range list {
//             if !seen[link] {
//                 seen[link] = true
//                 unseenLinks <- link
//             }
//         }
//     }
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, I think the author is talking about the go routine in below:

```
go func() { worklist <- foundLinks }()
```

> Links found by crawl are sent to the worklist from a dedicated
> goroutine to avoid deadlock.

Why must this go exist?